# Cannot 'gotoscene' with Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have tried, tried and tried. But cannot get this to work.

All I have it main.lua with a button in it. I then want this to go to about.lua.

My main.lua is:

```
local function about(event)
    storyboard.gotoScene( "about", {"Fade", 500} )
    return true
end

local about = widget.newButton
    {
        top = 280,
        width = 320,
        height = 66,
        defaultFile = "about.png",
        overFile = "aboutdown.png",
        onRelease = about
}
```

And my about.lua is:

```
local storyboard = require ( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
local widget = require ( "widget" )


local background = display.newImage( "logo.png" )
background.x = display.contentCenterX
background.y = display.contentCenterY
```

Please help!

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: There are no Errors, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? You are missing some very basic things discussed there like scene create/delete events, adding items to the scene etc. Where are you adding items to your scene object, in your code? Do some digging before posting.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [Storyboard API](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/index.html) you will see a template code you need to use to create a scene, copy all the template code to your about.lua and include your actual code in the createScene function, it should work.

First step: you create a new about.lua using the template code.

Second step: add your code in the createScene function like this, `background` and `widget` are forward declarations so they are before function calls

```
local widget = require ( "widget" )
local background

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --      CREATE display objects and add them to 'group' here.
    --      Example use-case: Restore 'group' from previously saved state.

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
background = display.newImage( "logo.png" )
background.x = display.contentCenterX
background.y = display.contentCenterY
end
```

Comment: Oh right, I am new you see so this is still a bit confusing. Is there an example that you could give me please? I am having trouble getting to grips with the scene stuff.

Comment: Oh right, well how do I create an about.lua using a template code? I just copied main.lua and changed the name and delted everything inside?

Comment: look for the template code at http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/index.html and copy that to a new blank about.lua